# Add two different Products with Custom Add-To-Cart() in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, cart

I'm trying to add multiple products with just one Click to my WooCommerce Cart.
This is my actual code:

```
jQuery("#button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addToCart(28,29,"Red");
    return false;
});

function addToCart(p_id,v_id,a_name) {
    jQuery.get('/wp/?post_type=product&add-to-cart='+p_id+'&variation_id='+v_id+'&attribute_color='+a_name, function() {
    });
}
```

At least I'm able to add one product, but I would like to add some more `addToCart()`-functions like:

```
addToCart(28,29,"Red");
addToCart(28,30,"Black");
addToCart(28,31,"Silver");
```

WooCommerce always only takes the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help..

I wrote a custom AJAX function for woocommerce to add multiple products to the cart. 
Doesnt support variable products, so would need some modifying but might provide a useful starting point...

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96139/consolidate-add-to-cart-buttons-into-one-add-all-to-cart-button/230564#230564

Comment: Thank you very much :] I will try this code in the next project. For the project in this topic i switched back to the PHP-Way.